# Why is there this error "configure: error: check config."?

Tags: macos, compiler-errors, g++, cpython

I cloned the cpython repository. https://github.com/python/cpython.git

When I run `configure`, the following error occurred.

```sh
➜  cpython git:(main) ./configure --with-pydebug && make -j
checking for git... found
checking build system type... x86_64-apple-darwin20.3.0
checking host system type... x86_64-apple-darwin20.3.0
checking for python3.11... no
checking for python3... python3
checking for --enable-universalsdk... no
checking for --with-universal-archs... no
checking MACHDEP... "darwin"
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /usr/bin/grep
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
checking for --with-cxx-main=<compiler>... no
checking for g++... no
configure:

  By default, distutils will build C++ extension modules with "g++".
  If this is not intended, then set CXX on the configure command line.

checking for the platform triplet based on compiler characteristics... darwin
checking for -Wl,--no-as-needed... no
checking for egrep... /usr/bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking minix/config.h usability... no
checking minix/config.h presence... no
checking for minix/config.h... no
checking whether it is safe to define __EXTENSIONS__... yes
checking for the Android API level... not Android
checking for --with-suffix...
checking for case-insensitive build directory... yes
checking LIBRARY... libpython$(VERSION)$(ABIFLAGS).a
checking LINKCC... $(PURIFY) $(MAINCC)
checking EXPORTSYMS...
checking for GNU ld... no
checking for --enable-shared... no
checking for --enable-profiling... no
checking LDLIBRARY... libpython$(VERSION)$(ABIFLAGS).a
checking for ar... ar
checking for readelf... no
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... ./install-sh -c -d
checking for --with-pydebug... yes
checking for --with-trace-refs... no
checking for --with-assertions... implied by --with-pydebug
checking for --enable-optimizations... no
checking PROFILE_TASK... -m test --pgo --timeout=$(TESTTIMEOUT)
checking for --with-lto... no
checking for llvm-profdata... no
configure: llvm-profdata found via xcrun: /usr/bin/xcrun llvm-profdata
checking for -Wextra... yes
checking whether gcc accepts and needs -fno-strict-aliasing... no
checking if we can turn off gcc unused result warning... yes
checking if we can turn off gcc unused parameter warning... yes
checking if we can turn off gcc missing field initializers warning... yes
checking if we can turn on gcc mixed sign comparison warning... yes
checking if we can turn on gcc unreachable code warning... no
checking if we can turn on gcc strict-prototypes warning... yes
checking if we can make implicit function declaration an error in gcc... yes
checking if we can use visibility in gcc... yes
checking which compiler should be used... gcc
checking which MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET to use... 11.2
checking if specified universal architectures work... no
configure: error: check config.log and use the '--with-universal-archs' option
➜  cpython git:(main)
```

My computer version is `macOS Big Sur 11.2.3` .

Comment: I had same issue, I had to re-install [xcode CLI tools](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/1738#issuecomment-781669699)

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM  Thank you very much! This is very helpful. Furthermore, is this useful because the tool is damaged or outdated ?

Comment: I am not sure about that, I encounter this issue for the repos having version > 3.9.